# how to import an oracle apex application export file from a lower version (4.2) into a higher version (18.1)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-18.2

[image]

I face error

> expected WHITELISTED_EXCUTE_IMMEDIATE_EXPRESSION

while trying to import APEX 4.2 application into APEX 18.1. I even removed the block of code which arise the error but still face same error with other page no.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing this through the Apex Designer? It looks like this is a known bug. Try executing the exported Apex script in sqlplus.
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4173070/error-installing-4-2-application-in-18-1

Answer (score 0):

```
Export your apps
open your apps any text editor like notepad, notepad++
change p_version_yyyy_mm_dd & p_release

wwv_flow_api.import_begin (
p_version_yyyy_mm_dd => '2020.02.24',
p_release            => '4.2.x.xx.xx'
 .....
```

There's no guarantee that it'll actually work, but - if you're desperate enough, try it. I hope it'll help.

For more info please visit [this link](https://www.triology.de/en/web-en/database-applications-import-oracle-apex).